# how to add floating icon in Bottom Nav Bar?

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

How i can achive something like this for the center icon in a bottom nav bar?

[image: buttom]

Comment: [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) takes care of the button. The gap in the bar is not according to Material guidelines, but you might be able to achieve it with a properly positioned image perhaps?

Comment: I tired with a FAB but i cant bring it in front of the Bottom Nav, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my idea is to create two floating buttons one will be completely white and little bit bigger than original. you will put both on the same spot at the top of your bottom view and it will look like your background view is clipped.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#f12"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_circle"
    android:backgroundTint="#fff"
    android:padding="44dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.85"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_circle"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_offline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fab1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fab1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fab1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a component called BottomAppBar which can help you achieve this. You need to add this dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

Then your code should look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/your_layout_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="5dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_your_icon" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You application theme should also extend from this parent: `Theme.MaterialComponents`